# file_put_contents with jquery reload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I currently have a problem with php and javascript. Here is the thing : I'm trying to edit every few second a text file stored on the server, with the text the client wrote in a textarea (which id is 'area1')

The PHP :

```
<span id="write">
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['text']))
        {
                file_put_contents('file.txt', $_POST['text']);
        }
    ?>
</span>
```

The Javascript :

```
window.onload = function(){
    t = setInterval(load, 2000);

    function load()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: {
                text: $('#area1').val()
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {   
                $('#write').load('test.php #write');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, nothing is ever written in file.txt, even if we enter the isset condition (that I tested).

Why isn't it working ? Can't we use jquery load with file_put_contents ? Or maybe it is a silly mistake that I can't see...

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your logic in a JQuery doc ready `$( document ).ready(function() {....});` instead of the generic window.load?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still not work.

Comment: the jquery isnt the issue assuming it can find the test.php file. have you got php error reporting turned on?

Comment: Your PHP file doesn't return the contents of the file. If it is not writing to the file, that might be caused by permission problems. And might I suggest that you check if the input field has changed before you update it. That way you won't be making any unnecessary requests to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using $.post? It is simpler and clearer.
Below is the full working code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
    <textarea id="area1"></textarea>
    <textarea id="write"></textarea>
</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    t = setInterval(load, 2000);

    function load()
    {
        $.post( "test.php", { text: $('#area1').val() })
            .done(function( data ) {
                    $('#write').load('test.php #write');
                    });
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And also make sure your php script has a privilege to add files.
Use `(sudo) chown apache *folder*` or similar.

Good luck!

Comment: And also if you're trying to load the file content back to the #write textarea, change the **done** function to this:

`$('#write').load('file.txt');`

Comment: Can you print the $_POST array on php side and post the result here?
Add `print_r($_POST);` in your php code and see the response in chrome's or firefox's network tab (in developer tools).

Comment: Also, please, debug the `$('#area1').val()` statement in the browser console to be sure you're not making any silly mistakes regarding element ids.

Comment: Finally, thanks to you, I managed to make this work. I changed the what is in the .done with .load('file.txt') and, with some adaptations, it works ! Thank you very much !